# Restricted Youtube access

Tags: monitoring

Is it possible to enforce from Fortigate a restriction on Youtube access?
We want to allow Youtube access for some of our employees who work in Media, but we want to enforce some sort of rule or policy that still enables the blocking of Adult Material and the like.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer might be found [here](https://www.fortinet.com/support-and-training/support-services/fortiguard-security-subscriptions/web-filtering.html). There's a subscription Fortinet offers for content filtering of all sorts.

Disclaimer: I have no experience at all with Fortinet products. I simply did a Google search for that link.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I've been using Fortigate 5.6 on our network for a while, and we've had Youtube restriction since I joined this organization so it was never required before to worry about who gets Youtube access and who doesn't. Anyway, thank you for the link reference - it doesn't quite get as specific as my requirement. But appreciated anyway.

Comment: @Aps Sorry it wasn't what you're looking for. We do have some Fortigates for one of our contracts but it's a different engineer that manages those devices, so I've never needed to interact with them.  Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you filter Youtube access in your normal Internet access policy. Then you add a new policy on top of that, permitting your desired group access to YT, using whatever other filters and policies you need.

You'll need to use YT's channel IDs in application control to narrow down access privileges. Since HTTPS is used, SSL deep inspection with certificate replacement is required. Don't use the factory certificate because it might expose your users to MitM attacks but create and deploy your own CA root certificate.

You could also try the *parental control* on the streaming media category, but I haven't used that.